# Dart is getting hung while using high CPU

Tags: linux, dart

I am building a web app using dart that has in its 'web' directory two sub-directories called 'data' and 'img' along with the other default directories. The 'img' directory has about 82000 png files using 1.1 GB. The 'data' directory has about 500 json files using 26M. The application is such that the user does *not* have to view all the data from all the files at once. Only small chunks will be sent.

When I issue a 'pub serve' command it utilizes 100% CPU and gets hung. I let it run for several hours and it never came back. Using the 'top' command I could see that 'dart' was using the maximum CPU. I removed those two directories from the web directory and pub worked and did not hang.

Is there anything I can do to prevent the hanging issue from happening?

Thanks for all your help!

P.S This happens on the latest of both stable and dev builds

Comment: I think this is worth a bug report. Are you using DDC?

Comment: I wasn't using ddc but switched over to it after you mentioned it. DDC hangs as well. I will put in a bug report. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to use a proxy in front of `pub serve` and move img and data out into their own directories that `pub serve` can't see.

Comment: Wow.  "pub serve" is ancient. :) This answer no longer applies.  If you want to serve a directory, I recommend package:dhttpd (found in pub.dev, and maintained by the Google team).